# Побайтовая запись в файл

Tags: java

```
    // String s = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Грызун.png";
    // String s2 = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Грызун_out.png";
    String s = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Грызун.txt";
    String s2 = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Грызун_out.txt";

    Reader reader = new FileReader(s);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(s2);

    while (true) {
        int f = reader.read();
        if (f == -1) break;
        out.write(f);
    }

    out.close();
```

Не могу понять, почему при побайтовом копировании второй файл не равен первому.

Пробовал картинку - безрезультатно.
Текстовый файл тоже неверно записывает, а конкретно: русский текст - крякозябрами.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

P.S.: Решил проблему. Хотя и не так быстро работает, ну да ладно... Вопрос не буду удалять, т.к. подобного поиском не нашел - вдруг кому пригодится.

Исправил строку

```
 Reader reader = new FileReader(s);
```

на

```
File file = new File(s);
FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream(file);
```